# How to use @JoinTable in Hibernate when I need multiple table interconnection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I began to work with JPA a few days ago and meet a first issue which I couldn't solve alone, so I need some help.
I need to implement the following schema with Hibernate:

[image]

Description:

- Object **Parent** has a collection of many children **Child**
- Object **Passport** has a collection of Parents which is subset of all available Parents from table **Parent**, and each **Parent** has a collection of children (**Child**) which is subset of all available children from table **Child**

My objects till now listed below. This works pretty well except that in **PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION** table it saves only **Passport** ID, not **Child** ID, what did I do wrong and how can I make it save **Child** ID too according to my interconnection design in picture above?

**Important! I haven't designed tables and I use a hibernate flag:      `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` to create tables from my entities.**

Thank you in advance!

**Parent**:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "parent")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private List<Child> children;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

**Child**:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false )
    private Parent parent;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

**Passport**:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Passport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar date;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION")
    private List<Parent> parents;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Join table is not necessary for OneToMany relationships, although they can be used.

In you Parent/Child relationship you have defined a OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationship using `Child.parent_id` as a Foreign Key. So you don’t need a join table for that relationship. You have not referred to your join table in either of these classes and therefore your JPA implementation will not add any columns to the join table based on this relationship.

You *have* referred to your join table in the Passport class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION")
private List<Parent> parents;
```

So JPA will create a PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION Table with columns corresponding to both sides for this relation: `Parent_ID`, `Passport_ID`.

If you *do* want to use a join table for all relationships, modify the Parent entity @OneToMany definition from;

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { 
CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "parent")
@Column(nullable = false)
private List<Child> children;
```

to;

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = 
{CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}) //Remove the mappedBy Attribute
@JoinTable(name="PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION")
private List<Child> children;
```

JPA will then create an additional column `children_id` in your `PASSPORT_PARENT_CHILDREN_CONNECTION` join table.

Note that you have the option to add a `passport_id` Foreign Key to the Parent table and use this in a Passport/Parent a OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationship just as you have done for Parent/Child. That would seem a better way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It will take few days (maybe more) to check if your solution is working and then I will give feedback or accept your answer.